# After update to Magento 2.3.1 the visibilty of Products ist wrong

Tags: products, catalogsearch, magento2.3.1

After I had "stupidly" made an update to Magento 2.31. I have the problem that my configurable child-products are displayed in the frontend.

In the admin-article-overview, the value is shown as "Catalog / Search" but in the detail view is right "not visible"

**Overview:**
[image]

**Detail:**
[image]

I tried everything but without success

```
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the value the same between store scopes?

Comment: i have only one store and one store view...

Comment: Even with one store you've got the 'All Store Views' global config and the store config

Comment: With only one Storeview I have no choice on the product side. This comes only when I create another Storeview. Or do I understand your question wrong?